# HTML, CSS: I'm trying to center a button on my page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center my button on the page, but can't seem to get it right.
I've tried to auto de left and right margins but didn't work. And I don't want to center it by gut feeling in percentages. Can somebody help me out, would appreciate it. It's for my intership :D

here u have the html. I used basic html and pure grids and bootstrap:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>karakters page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylekarakters.css">

</head>
<body>

  <div class="fixed-bg">
    <div class="pure-g">

      <div class="pure-u-1-2">
        <a href="#null" class="homeknop" onclick="window.location.href='index.html';">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1">
        <img class="pure-img logo" src="img/Karakters-logo_ZW2.png"></img>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pure-g">

      <div class="pure-u-1">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <img class="pure-img" src="img/pic-karakters.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1">
        <h1 class="reveal1">
          <strong>Ontwerp- en communicatiebureau.<br>Groot geworden in de boeken, <br>met  grafiek in de genen</strong>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u-1">
        <div class="textcontainer">
          <h2><strong>Nu bieden we het hele pallet aan communicatieondersteuning.</strong></h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pure-u-1-5">
        <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon-strategy.png" />
        <h4>strategische begeleiding <br>(ook pers en digitaal)</h4>
      </div>

          <div class="pure-u-1-5">
            <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon-web.png" />
            <h4>webontwikkeling</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="pure-u-1-5">
            <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon-campagne.png" />
            <h4>creëren van campagnes</h4>
          </div>


          <div class="pure-u-1-5">
            <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon-expo.png" />
            <h4>maken van tentoonstellingen als grafische vormgeving</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="pure-u-1-5">
            <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon-boeken.png" />
            <h4>ontwerpen en zetten <br>van boeken, etc.</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="pure-u-1-5"></div>

      </div>


    <div class="pure-g">

      <div class="pure-u-1"><h2><strong>We zijn er voor u, allemaal!</strong></h2></div>

      <div class="pure-u-1-4">
        <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon_nonprofit-3.png" />
        <h4>non-profit</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-4">
        <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon_government-3.png" />
        <h4>overheid</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-4">
        <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon_uitgeverij-4.png" />
        <h4>uitgeverijen</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-4">
        <img class="pure-img icon" src="img/icon_profit-3.png" />
        <h4>profit</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-3"></div>
      <div class="pure-u-1-3"></div>

      <div class="pure-u-1">
        <h2>Kortom: alles op maat van de opdrachtgever.<br>Maar altijd vanuit hetzelfde kader:
          <br><strong> duurzaam, kwalitatief</strong> en <strong>authentiek</strong>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u-1">
        <h4 class="projecten">projecten</h4>
      </div>

          <div class="pure-u-1">
            <button onclick="window.location.href='catpageK.html';" class="buttonK"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>







      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
      <script src="scriptkarakterspage.js"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the css, also basic:

```
body{
  background-color: rgba(111, 179, 160, 0.1);
  margin-top: 5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 90%;

}

.imgcontainer .pure-img {
  max-width: 40%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 3em;
}
.icon{
  max-width: 66%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


 /* h3
}
{
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-top: 100px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
} */

 h1,h2{
  padding:1em;
  text-align: center;
}
h4{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.pure-u-1 .textcontainer p {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;

}
.textcontainer{
    margin-top: 5em;
}

.pure-img.logo {
    max-width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -55px;
}

.projecten {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 2em;
  color:#6fb3a0;
}

div .pure-u-1 .buttonK
{
     border: solid #6fb3a0 2px;
    background-color: #6fb3a0;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    text-align: center;


}

div.pure-u-1 button.buttonK{
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-top: 1.5em;


}

a {
    margin-left: 100px;
    color:#6fb3a0;
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPQfb.png)

Comment: Don't understand why you need `margin-left: 50%;` just use `display: block;` and `margin: 0 auto;` and give the width which is required by your button for example `width: 50px;`

Comment: Why isn't `div.pure-u-1 button.buttonK { margin: 1.5em auto 2em; }` not working?

Comment: It would have been better if you could have added the required component in code snippet and shown. Others can edit that snippet and help you out. I tried editing your question and adding the code that you wrote into a snippet but there are 'stylekarakters.css' and 'scriptkarakterspage.js' missing that breaks the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

Give `left:50%` to your `button`, and then have half of is size and put in negative in the `margin-left`

```
div.pure-u-1 button.buttonK {
    left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/qsthLt27/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

There's a really easy way with CSS3 when you push something from the left by 50%:

```
.class {
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Works vertically as well with `transform: translateY(-50%);`.

The 2 can be combined as `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);`.

> You may need to add vendor-specific prefixes when using this. Searching for "CSS auto prefix" should yield online services to do it quickly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add `display:block;` to the button. That will make the `margin:auto;` work.

```css
.buttonK {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-u-1">
  <button onclick="window.location.href='catpageK.html';" class="buttonK">Button</button>
</div>
```